# ZFS pool with disks labels /dev/disk/by-id/scsi*** disappeared after upgrade

Tags: disk, zfs

Recently I have upgraded my home server from 13.04 to 13.10 by dist-upgrade
and my zfs pool which was built using .../by-id/scsi*** disk names broke

The problem is that scsi*** labels completely disappeared. Only ata*** left.
What is the difference between same disk under ata or scsi labels?
What could be reason?

The hardware is
HP Microsever N54L with 2TB WD disks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the command `zfs import` to scan your disks for pools and rebuild them.

Use `zfs import` for a list of pools and `zfs import <pool>` to import any detected pools and their configurations.

`zfs import` will scan all the devices for pools and configuration and attach the found devices to their rightful pools, no matter the name of the device on the your system, if the disk is present zfs will set it online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try that ZFS!
But still ...
What that prefix ata/scsi mean to the system? Why scsi gone?
Should I bother?

Comment: No, that is just the device name while using the new kernel, if your drives are there then it should be fine, else a downgrade to a previous kernel will name your drives the same that they were... But zfs keeps its config in the pools you create, not in the system you are using.

Comment: Is there way to check, that drive is working in rigth SATA/AHCI mode and not something like ATA emulation etc?

Comment: You can check the SATA link speed and status with `sudo dmesg | grep SATA` and if you are using AHCI with `sudo dmesg | grep ahci`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 at least, it seems to be `zpool import` not `zfs import`